# How to convert from a pressure to force under a wave?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, fluid-dynamics, pressure

I have an experiment result, which measures the dynamic force on a force plate under a wave. I am comparing this with theoretical results. Most theories, however, state the value in terms of pascals, whereas I have my values in Newtons. Simple conversion using P=F/A doesn't seem to work as there seems to be a difference of a factor of 10. I don't think the theory is incorrect since they have very similar values.

Is there a way to convert pressure to force or vice versa that I'm not doing? I read something about the center of pressure but I'm not sure what to do with that information.

I have added a quick sketch of the experiment setup. Note the dimensions of the force plate are considerably smaller than the wavelength (which is around 8.5 m) and the force plate is located at a depth of 2 m. My results show a vertical force peak of around 3 N but the theory predicts around 120 pa. I also get the horizontal forces and moments, so is there a way of reconstructing with those values as well?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: A drawing showing the shape, orientation, and depth of your pressure plate would greatly help.

Comment: Well, in general, P=F/A. Are you sure you’re using the right area? Is there some sort of effective area that would be more appropriate? Without more details, it would be hard for us to tell.

Comment: Probably the wave is exerting its force of 3N (assuming it is right) on a smaller area of the plate. Without more details, it is hard to tell more ;)

Comment: @David White I have added a quick sketch.

Comment: @Gilbert That's what i am unsure about, I don't think my results or the theory is wrong. I read somewhere the Force Plates have a larger footprint but wouldn't that effectively mean an increase in area, which means greater disparity.

Comment: There could be a "bug" in your theory. If I were you, I would place the force plate at the bottom of a tank and try to back out the hydrostatic pressure. That would be a simple validation exercise to confirm that there is nothing wrong with your instruments, your hydrostatic pressure model, or your calculations. That would basically confirm that there is something wrong with your wave model.

Comment: @Evan I cannot repeat the experiment but the force plate is located at the bottom of the tank. The value is essentially the added force due to the wave peak. On the other hand, the theory is indeed very realistic here considering the wave peak of 0.03m.

Comment: Does your recording from the force plate include a time when before the waves were generated?

Comment: @Evan Yes, it is centred at zero.

Comment: So the force from the force plate is registered as zero when there are no waves being generated?

Comment: @Evan Yes, so only the dynamic forces are derived.